# mobile browsers, cap program and position fixed

Tags: javascript, css, html, mobile, fixed

Good afternoon.
There was a very unexpected problem with mobile browsers (eg Chrome 32. * )
These browsers have not fixed the upper panel, which appears / removed with scrolling.

There is vertically fixed block (`position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%;` etc).

Somehow, it redraws only happens when you release your finger from the screen. Because it is a floating toolbar occurs abruptly, it looks awful.

The fixed position of the browser supports. The only problem is panel.
Is there a way to dynamically change the location or even ignore the panel?
Many thanks to all responded

Comment: what do you mean to ignore?
Are you want to hide your panel?

Comment: I want to "div" does not depend on the program caps or moved smoothly when it appears

Comment: Any ideas? The problem is not rare because